# Ruby binary method <<=

Tags: ruby, binary, documentation

This is several questions wrapped in one. I saw the method "<<=" used recently. I was able to piece together what is does, but not anything else about it.

```
$ dec = 2  
$ dec <<= 1  
=> 4  
$ dec  
=> 4  
$ dec <<= 2  
=> 16
```

I think it's basically a shortcut for multiplying the sum plus the next nth position's in binary:

```
$ a = 2 * 2 ** 1  
=> 4  
$ a = a * 2 ** 2
=> 16
```

It doesn't work if you try it on a fixnum itself

```
$ 4 <<= 1  
=> SyntaxError: unexpected tOP_ASGN, expecting end-of-input  
1 <<= 1  
     ^
```

I searched for hours and couldn't find where it lives in the ruby docs.

- Where is there documentation for this?
- What class or module does this live in?
- Why does is only work if you assign it to a variable first?

Thanks!

Comment: The `a <<= b` is a short form for `a = a << b`.

Comment: @Michas has your answer. It's similar to `+=`, `||=` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called an *abbreviated assignment* and is covered in section 11.4.2.3 *Abbreviated Assignments* of the [ISO Ruby Language Specification](http://iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=59579); specifically it is an *abbreviated variable assignment* (§11.4.2.3.2).

An abbreviated variable assignment is evaluated (roughly) like this:

```
a ω= b
```

is the same as

```
a = a ω b
```

where `ω` is an arbitrary non-equality Ruby operator (`&&`, `||`, `&`, `|`, `^`, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `**`, `%`, `<<`, `>>`).

Note: this simple translation applies only to abbreviated variable assignments. It does *not* apply to *abbreviated indexing assignments* (`a[b] ω= b`) or *abbreviated method assignments* (`a.b ω= c`).

> - Where is there documentation for this?

While the ISO Ruby Language Specification covers only a small subset of the intersection of Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9, abbreviated assignments *are* covered there.

They are also covered in the [Ruby RDocs](http://ruby-doc.org/) under [`syntax/assignment.rdoc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Abbreviated+Assignment).

> - What class or module does this live in?

None. Assignments are a language feature, not a library feature.

> - Why does is only work if you assign it to a variable first?

I am not sure what you mean. It works perfectly fine without assigning to a variable first:

```
class NilClass; def <<(*) :haha end end

a <<= a
#=> :haha
```

Comment: It was returning an error message when I was using it like this:  `1 <<= 1`
Which with what you showed makes sense since I would be trying to assign a value to a fixnum.  `1 = 1 << 1` Is that correct?

Comment: Ah, yes. That is correct. So, you *don't* need to assign it to a variable *first*, but you *do* need to assign it to a variable *at all*. If that makes sense.

Comment: It does. Thanks Jörg W Mittag!